# C# FFmpeg / NReco.VideoConverter: Increase Conversion Speed

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I use NReco.VideoConverter for video conversion.
How can I increase video conversion speed and get a maximum performance?
Theory says, that it is possible to increase video conversion:

- rise processor cores quantity;
- rise CPU frequency  (set more powerful processor(s));
- set outer video adapter to use GPU.

There several questions:

- can FFmpeg / NReco.VideoConverter use several cores/processor(s) at
  once and how?
- can FFmpeg / NReco.VideoConverter use GPU or it depends from video
  codec installed in OS?

What factors can influence on conversion process?

Comment: dunno about NReco but some encoders FFmpeg leverages can use multiple cores https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264

Comment: @Chaki_Black Do you get any solution of this ? I have similar problem

Comment: @SanketPatel, sorry, but I don't have an exact answer. I tried to deploy project with conversion process to Azure server, but middle packets never allow to get a good performance, but, I think even the best of Azure packet does not allow... What I know about performance – should rise CPU frequency (set more powerful processor(s)) and rent dedicated server and not the single. No mentions in FFmpeg areas about the usage of GPUs for execution (maybe OS does it by default if .NET platform or other allows) or cores quantity.